# Create new column based on number of different values in column grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB         |ColumnZ |
| --------| --------------  |--------|
| 1       | locationA       |324     |
| 1       | n.a.            |34      |
| 2       | n.a.            |21      |
| 2       | locationA       |n.a.    |
| 2       | locationA       |34      |
| 2       | n.a.            |12      |
| 3       | n.a.            |1       |
| 3       | locationB       |134     |
| 3       | n.a.            |n.a.    |
| 4       | n.a.            |134     |
| 4       | locationC       |n.a.    |
| 4       | locationD       |132     |
| 4       | locationD       |n.a.    |
```

I now want to add a new `ColumnC`, in which is stated "different locations", when more than 1 location is in `ColumnB` that belong to the same group (i.e. same number) in `ColumnA`. So my desired output is:

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB         | ColumnZ | ColumnC             |
| --------| --------------  | --------| -----------------   |
| 1       | locationA       | 324     |                     |
| 1       | n.a.            | 34      |                     |
| 2       | n.a.            | 21      |                     |
| 2       | locationA       | n.a.    |                     |
| 2       | locationA       | 34      |                     |
| 2       | n.a.            | 12      |                     |
| 3       | n.a.            | 1       |                     |
| 3       | locationB       | 134     |                     |
| 3       | n.a.            | n.a.    |                     |
| 4       | n.a.            | 134     | different locations |
| 4       | locationC       | n.a.    | different locations |
| 4       | locationD       | 132     | different locations |
| 4       | locationD       | n.a.    | different locations |
```

Therefore I've started with turning all `n.a.` values in `ColumnB` to `NaN` values:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].replace('n.a.', np.NaN)
```

and then I've tried it with this function:

```
def no_of_locations(group):
    if df['ColumnB'].nunique() > 1:
        df['ColumnC'] = 'different locations'
    pass

df.groupby('ColumnA').apply(no_of_locations)
```

Yet, the result is that it still counts all unique values in the whole `ColumnB`, not only in the group based on `ColumnA`. How can I restrict it on the respective group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only condition is having repeating ColumnA after dropping na values you can just count the number of ColumnA values and use it to mask and filter your original dataframe

```
mask = df['ColumnA'].isin((df.replace({'ColumnB' : {'n.a.': np.nan}})
                        .dropna(subset=['ColumnB'])
                        .groupby('ColumnA')['ColumnB'].nunique()
                        .loc[lambda x: x>1].index.values
)


df.loc[mask, 'ColumnC'] = 'different_locations'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. You did not include ```ColumnB``` (which is the column the condition is based on) and I'm not sure why you code ```.query('ColumnA == 1')``` (as it should do the same for every value in ```ColumnA``` (which stands for a group on its own) ?

Comment: It does work though. Latter ```.query``` is done on the result of ```value_counts```. It counts the number of  columns after dropping the na values therefore if there are repeating values for a group it will be selected. If your only condition is having multiple columnB's for a group this will work

Comment: I changed the query to be understood more easily but it still behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I've figured out why it does not work with my original dataset - I have other columns that are affected by the ```replace('n.a.', np.nan).dropna()```, that's why I don't get any values in the new ```ColumnC```. I've edited my post so you can understand what I mean. Is there a way to restrict the ```replace('n.a.', np.nan).dropna()``` only to ```ColumnB```?

Comment: Yes of course. You can use subset. I edited the answer accordingly. Hopefully this answers your question

Comment: Thank you, subset is a good idea! I've checked again why the original data set is still producing wrong results and the reason is that your solution is taking the unique values (by value_counts) from the wrong column (not ```ColumnB```). I've edited my example data in the question to make this clear to you. So in case of group ```2``` in ```ColumnA```,  there should be printed nothing in ```ColumnC```, as there is only two times ```locationA``` and besides that only ```NaN``` values (so in total just one location). Do you have any idea of how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Sure. You just have to groupby using A and count unique values of B. I edited the answer according to your needs. Hopefully if helps

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works perfectly! Your help is very much appreciated - çok teşekkürler!